# How do I hack RC transmitter of my drone by realised communication with my PC?

Tags: quadcopter, arduino, control, radio-control

I have a Chinese drone (cost less than $100), that works with a 2.4Ghz transmitter of 2.4. I am trying to build an application in C++ to control the drone with PC. I am thinking of using an ARDUINO and a NRF24L01 module.  But I have not been able to establish communication with the drone. I don`t understanding the form of communication very well, is there a post, information, book, blog or idea that can help me?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Juan Camanei, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.